# Neurons and nerves

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neurology

What is a nerve compared to a neuron? Is it a collection of axons alone or does it include cell body too? I'm pretty confused of what actually the "nerve" is composed of. I had imagined that the nerve is actually having a no of neurons synapsing together but I guess it's not so.. Pls do make a clear demarcation between a neuron, nerve,  nerve fibre, ganglia, nuclei

Comment: @novo  I vote to close the question too

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather broad question, but the categorization is as follows:

- A **neuron** is a cell of the nervous system, its role is the transmission of electric signals.
- A **nerve** is a bundle of axons, meaning that it contains neurons but only part of them.
- A **nerve fiber** is another (and in my experience rarely used) term for an axon.
- A **ganglion** is an aggregation of neuron cell bodies in the peripheral (i.e. autonomous and sensory) nervous systems.
- A **nucleus** is an aggregation of neuron cell bodies in the central nervous system.

As you can deduce from the info above, a nerve is distinct from a neuron and does not include its cell body.